# insert on table being unnaturally slow

Tags: performance, azure-sql-database, insert, data

I have an "Basic" pricing tier Azure SQL database with a table of 7 columns, an ID column of int that is the clustered index and primary key, one datetime2(0) column, 3 varchar(100) columns and 2 varchar(MAX) columns, all nullable.

The table has no triggers, constraints or foreign keys.

Now I'm inserting a large amount of test data, I'm doing an

```
INSERT INTO table_name (<all columns, except the ID one>)
values (<just some values, the ones for varchar(MAX) being 221 characters long>)`
GO 680000
```

However the query has been running for 5 hours and only 290000 rows have been inserted.

I'm trying to find out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to look at the waits for the session doing the insert to figure out what the bottleneck is. Given that you are on a "Basic" tier, your insert is probably being artificially throttled based on the service tier.

If you run a query like this...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats
WHERE session_id = <session doing the insert>
ORDER BY wait_time_ms DESC
```

...I suspect you'll see that the top wait is probably something like `LOG_RATE_GOVERNOR` or `HADR_THROTTLE_LOG_RATE_GOVERNOR`. [These wait types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-logical-server#transaction-log-rate-governance) are caused specifically due to the artificial limits put on the rate at which you can write to the transaction log in Azure SQL DB, and is a common bottleneck on large inserts when using the Basic Tier. The Basic Tier is **extremely** limited on available system resources. Note: It's possible to hit the limit on log rate without hitting the service tier's DTU limit.

One solution is to simply use a higher service tier, which will allow you to have more DTUs (and thus more overall system resources) to use for your large insert. After your load is complete, you can then switch back to a lower service tier. I've written more about DTUs, and attempted to correlate DTUs back to traditional on-prem hardware you may be more familiar with --you can read that [here](https://am2.co/2017/03/what-the-heck-is-a-dtu/).

There may be more options for improving throughput on a lower service tier, but to do so, you'll need to look in detail at exactly what you're doing, and what your resource bottleneck is.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me how to get the session ID of the session doing the insert? Also I'm noticing the database isn't using more than 20% DTU in the azure portal page. I thought the 100% would be the max for the tier but is that wrong?

Comment: It's possible to hit the log rate limit without hitting the DTU threshold--though both DTUs and log rate limits increase as you go up service tiers. I've made an edit to clarify.

Comment: To find the session ID of the session doing the insert, this is shown in the SSMS tab name (at the end of the tab name in parentheses), or you can use a tool like `sp_whoisactive` or query the DMVs `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and/or `sys.dm_exec_requests` to find info about other active sessions.

Comment: Welp, my top `wait_type` is "WRITELOG" so you're right, Azure is throttling writing of the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Single row inserts (especially followed by an implicit commit) are going to generate a LOT more transaction log data than bulk inserts.

Using a transaction log backup as a rough and ready example of how much transaction log data gets written:

```
CREATE TABLE new_employees  
(  
 id_num int IDENTITY(1,1),  
 fname varchar (20),  
 minit char(1),  
 lname varchar(30),
 lob_col varchar(max)
);  

set nocount on 
BACKUP LOG [demo_db] TO  DISK = N'V:\SQL\Backups\demo_db_log_clear.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'demo_db-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
select getdate()
go
insert into new_employees  
(  
 fname 
,minit 
,lname 
,lob_col 
)
values
('Andrew'
,'J'
,'Sayer'
,replicate('X',221)
);
go 100000
select getdate()
BACKUP LOG [demo_db] TO  DISK = N'V:\SQL\Backups\demo_db_log_single.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'demo_db-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
select getdate()
go
insert into new_employees  
(  
 fname 
,minit 
,lname 
,lob_col 
)
select top 100000
 'Andrew'
,'J'
,'Sayer'
,replicate('X',221)
FROM sys.all_columns ac
cross join sys.all_columns ac2
go
select getdate()
go
BACKUP LOG [demo_db] TO  DISK = N'V:\SQL\Backups\demo_db_log_bulk.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'demo_db-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

(I'm using 100,000 rows as I got impatient waiting for the single value inserts to finish with your counts).

The results on my home machine:

```
Single row insert
Time taken: 2021-08-16 20:49:41.510 to 2021-08-16 20:50:04.477 = 23 seconds
Transaction log backup size: 50010 pages

Bulk row insert
Time taken: 2021-08-16 20:50:04.787 to 2021-08-16 20:50:05.177 = 0.4 seconds
Transaction log backup size: 4601 pages
```

So it's roughly 50 times faster and generates a tenth of the transaction log data.

Only thing to make sure is that the row generation source can generate enough rows, I just cross joined `sys.all_columns` with itself which produces plenty in my pretty empty database.